Issue with 'libgmp-10.dll' in Ruby while compaling script with Ocra
I'm having an issue while trying to create an executable with ocra in Ruby and I'm not able to fix it no matter what, even chatGPT couldn't help.
The issue is with libgmp-10.dll. The compiler works correctly, but when I try to execute the .exe file, it drops the following issue:

Any suggestions? I reinstalled Ruby many times, from v3.3 to v3.0 and even v2.7 don't work. I also reinstalled ocra several times but nothing works.
I have tried the following commands:

ocra Image_Hunter.rb
ocra Image_Hunter.rb --no-dep-run --console.

I also tried specifying the .dll that is supposedly missing with ocra Image_Hunter.rb --dll C:\Ruby27-x64\bin\ruby_builtin_dlls\libgmp-10.dll --no-dep-run --console but the .EXE is not even created, as I got an error:
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:120:in `new': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)


Can you post the ocra command you used and the output? Maybe this comment will help you?

@engineersmnky I tried with pretty much every output: ocra Image_Hunter.rb, ocra Image_Hunter.rb --no-dep-run --console. I also try by specifying the .dll that is supposedly missing with ocra Image_Hunter.rb --dll C:\Ruby27-x64\bin\ruby_builtin_dlls\libgmp-10.dll --no-dep-run --console. With the latter, the .EXE is not even created, as I got an error: C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:120:in `new': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

I solved the issue by running the command in this way ocra Image_Hunter.rb --no-lzma --gem-full --add-all-core --output build\temp\output.exe --dll ruby_builtin_dlls/libgmp-10.dll --dll ruby_builtin_dlls/libffi-8.dll --dll ruby_builtin_dlls/zlib1.dll --dll ruby_builtin_dlls/libiconv-2.dll --dll ruby_builtin_dlls\libssl-1_1-x64.dll --dll ruby_builtin_dlls\libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll --dll ruby_builtin_dlls\libyaml-0-2.dll --dll ruby_builtin_dlls/libwinpthread-1.dll --gem-full=openssl --gem-full=tzinfo-data
